# React Native NativeModules Empty Object

Tags: react-native, native-module

Trying to create my first npm module in order to determine if a user is on the phone. It's for a React Native app. No matter what I try, the module returns undefined. NativeModules always appears to be an empty object.

Please help! Below is a link to the code. `export default RNOnPhoneCall;` in `index.js` will only return undefined. How do I link the functions in `ios` folder, and export them in `index.js`? Heads up, `android` is not up to date yet, only `ios`.

[Link to Github](https://github.com/torihuang/react-native-on-phone-call/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not exporting the method correctly in my iOS file. Here's the solution, along with a link to the final project.

[react-native-check-phone-call-status on github](https://github.com/torihuang/react-native-check-phone-call-status)

```
#import "RNCheckPhoneCallStatus.h"
#import "React/RCTLog.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCallCenter.h>
#import<CoreTelephony/CTCall.h>

@implementation RNCheckPhoneCallStatus

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(get:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
    NSString *phoneStatus = @"PHONE_OFF";
    CTCallCenter *ctCallCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    if (ctCallCenter.currentCalls != nil)
    {
        NSArray* currentCalls = [ctCallCenter.currentCalls allObjects];
        for (CTCall *call in currentCalls)
        {
            if(call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
            {
                phoneStatus = @"PHONE_ON";
            }
        }
    }
    callback(@[[NSNull null], phoneStatus]);
}

@end
```

Comment: Also if you are following the [react tutorial](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#export-a-native-method-to-javascript) it is a bit misleading. It will work with debug mode turned on. If you want it to work without debug mode you need the callback mentioned here.

Answer (score 8):

After snooping around a little, I found out that the Obj-C file isn't added to the Compile Sources in Xcode. Just follow me:
Let's say the file names are: `NotchNative.h` and `NotchNative.m`. If the `NotchNative.m` file is not listed, the files will not be compiled by Xcode hence it needs to be added to the Compile Sources.

[image]

Follow the steps in the image and rebuild/run the iOS app again.
It's surely a fault on the Xcode side, as it doesn't happen in case of Swift projects.

Comment: Thanks so much. No wonder the RN docs recommend creating and editing files via XCode.

Answer (score 3):

Try rebuilding your project. I faced the same issue recently and simply rebuilding resolved it